# Ubuntu 20.04 - Merging New Working FIlesystem Partition Into Broken Filesystem Partition

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, filesystem, data-recovery

I messed up my Linux filesystem through some bad `chmod` commands on my Dell XPS 9310. It got to the point where `sudo` was unusable and I couldn't open new terminal windows or boot up again after finally restarting.

I used Dell's OS Recovery Tool to create a new filesystem partition with a clean install. The old partition is available mounted through the recovery process.

Am I able to recover use of the original filesystem partition and setup in any way with the new partition? I'm happy that my files were retained, but going back to my original setup would be ideal. Below is some output of the various partitions.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
...
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: PC SN530 NVMe WDC 256GB                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 576A3193-3D43-407F-9266-64CE5427EAEB

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1        34    488281    488248 238.4M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    488282   8728558   8240277     4G Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3   8728576 352323249 343594674 163.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p4 352323584 500117503 147793920  70.5G Linux filesystem
```

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0 238.4M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     4G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 163.9G  0 part /media/my_user/UBUNTU
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0  70.5G  0 part /
```

Comment: Copying over your old home directory to your new one or even mounting it on top of the new one will restore most your personal settings for e.g. Firefox, Thunderbird ... and other apps ... copying other system directories, however, is not advised at all and will bring the old problems with it to the new installation.

Comment: Would that be done through the file manager/terminal with a restart or would changes be automatically recognized?

Comment: i added an answer ... I hope it helps ... please let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `/dev/nvme0n1p3` is the partition holding your old Ubuntu system and `/dev/nvme0n1p4` is the partition created during recovery and holding your current running Ubuntu system.

You can use the file manager from the GUI *(make sure you copy **hidden directories and files** that start with `.` in their names and you can show them by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)* to Copy over the contents of your old home i.e. `/home/yourusername/*` directory from `/dev/nvme0n1p3` that is currently mounted under `/media/` to your new one i.e `/home/yourusername/` on `/dev/nvme0n1p4` that is currently mounted on the system root directory `/`.

Or you can copy from the terminal like so:

```
cp -r /full_path/to/old_home/* /full_path/to/new_home/
```

This will restore most your personal settings for e.g. Firefox, Thunderbird ... and other apps along with other customization *(You need to reinstall those apps)*. Then all you need to do is logout and login again to fully use the customized settings in your home directory after the copy process.

On the other hand, copying any other system directories and files is not advised at all and will bring the old problems with it to the new installation.